# Is strict aliasing is c or c++ thing?

Tags: c++, c, casting, strict-aliasing

In ISO/IEC 9899:TC2, the standard says following

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> 1. A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different
>      object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the pointed-to type, the behavior is undeﬁned. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of
>      the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

So, it is not clear from the standard that a pointer of one type can be casted to pointer of another type.

Comment: "A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type." -- how is it not clear?

Comment: David, the thing that is not clear is, if it is undefined to cast a pointer of one type to pointer of other as the standard says, "A pointer to an object may be converted to a pointer to a different object"

Comment: chappar: the pointer conversion itself is well-defined within the restrictions above; the aliasing rules only apply when actually using the pointer to access the pointed-to object, and Kos already quoted the relevant parts of the standard...

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco "_how is it not clear?_" What is not clear here is what the result of cast is, except for `char`.

Comment: @curiousguy: It's clear what the result is: "... when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "when converted back again" why would anyone use `reinterpret_cast` to convert a type back to itself? That is what `void*` and `static_cast` is for. `reinterpret_cast` is for converting to a different type, and using the pointer.

Comment: @curiousguy: I don't disagree with anything you're saying. I'm just pointing out that it's very clear what the result of the cast is -- "... when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer." The result is that result such that when converted back to the original type, it will compare equal.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The quoted paragraph ends with "is unspecified." Is there any reason why `reinterpret_cast` is defined in a term of `static_cast`, BTW?

Comment: @curiousguy: There's no way the standard can specify what the result of accessing one type through a pointer to another type is (other than `char *`) because that's going to be platform-dependent. The definition of `reinterpret_cast` in terms of `static_cast` was likely just to be more concise, since `static_cast` was already defined.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Of course the result of reading data with the "wrong" type is not specified. What about the result of **writing** using a different type (aka reuse memory)? Is there even a guarantee that the result of `reinterpret_cast` can be copied to a variable? The memory manipulation casts are weakly specified.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14242/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-curiousguy)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Strict aliasing rule is defined somewhere else. This is the wording:

C (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.5/7):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualiﬁed version of a type compatible with the effective type of
>     the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the
>     effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a
>     qualiﬁed version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned
>     types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>     subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

C++ (ISO/IEC 14882:2011 3.10 [basicl.lval] / 15):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through
>   an lvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is
>   undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the
>     dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a
>     cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned
>     types among its elements or non-static data members (including,
>     recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate
>     or contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the
>     dynamic type of the object,
> - a `char` or `unsigned char` type.

---

The C standard doesn't prohibit you from casting the pointer to an unrelated type, provided there are no allignment problems. However, due to the strict aliasing rule, you basically can't dereference a pointer obtained from such a cast. So the only useful thing to do with such "invalid" pointer is to cast it back to the correct type (or a compatible type).

It's mostly the same in C++ with reinterpret_cast (5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] / 7):

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue `v` of type “pointer to `T1`” is converted to the type “pointer to *cv* `T2`”, the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`, or if either type is `void`. Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified.

Comment: @Charles Bailey, thanks for the edits, but to be strict you quoted C++ ISO/IEC 14882:2003 and before I've quoted [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) from Feb 2011 which is the latest C++ draft available. Since C++11 is [now official](http://herbsutter.com/2011/08/12/we-have-an-international-standard-c0x-is-unanimously-approved/), let's quote the currentmost spec, shall we? :)

Comment: It's not offical, the draft has been approved but it hasn't been published. If you want to quote the upcoming standard that's fine but as you didn't reference what you were quoting I didn't know that that is what you were doing.

Comment: I take it back, it was published on [Thusday](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372)!

Comment: Now we wait for Google to add another special case for C++11 so that I can find it :D Oh, wait, not available for free... Duh, seen that one coming :)

Comment: You can download it here: http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372

Comment: I've updated the references. You seem to have quoted C++03 for the `reinterpret_cast` quote originally before?

Comment: "_The C standard says it's not undefined to cast the pointer to an unrelated type, provided (...)_" "not undefined" is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks @curiousguy, I have fixed the poor wording and hope it's better now. (Feel free to edit the answer further if you wish, SO is collaboratively edited!)